# What addressing mode is used in 'mov cx, [bp+6]'?

Tags: x86-16, microprocessors, addressing-mode

What addressing mode is used in "mov cx, [bp+6]"? The processor is intel 8086. I am studying "Microprocessor and Interfacing" by Douglas V. Hall. I know its memory addressing mode. But not sure whether its based addressing mode or index addressing mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[bp+6]` is the based addressing mode. From the original 8086 docs:

> In based addressing, the effective address is the sum of a displacement value and the content of register BX or register BP.

Indexed addressing mode is similar but with the `SI` or `DI` registers.

Basically, you have the following modes:

- Direct memory accessing like `[1234]`.
- Register indirect like `[bx]`.
- Based addressing like `4[bx]` or `[bp+8]`.
- Indexed addressing like `4[si]` or `[di+4]`.
- Based indexed addressing (combo of the previous two) such as `4[bx][si]` or `[bx+si+4]`.
- Some other inconsequential (in this context) ones like implicit, port, string, relative.

Comment: isn't 6[bp] based addressing mode?

Comment: Actually, you're right, @eddard, I had to go back to the original docs.