# how do i move data from one address in the memory to another address in the memory(assembly)

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, x86-16

how do I move data from one address in the memory to another address in the memory(assembly)?

this is what I wrote and I Dont know if its correct.
can someone help?

```
mov ax,2000h
mov bx,3000h
mov cx,[ax]
mov [bx],cx
```

Comment: Use the debugger to single-step through and look at registers and memory.  Note that `[ax]` is not a valid 16-bit addressing mode, but `[bx]` and `[di]` are.  Other than that, looks ok.

Comment: why is [ax] not valid?

Comment: It's not encodeable into machine code. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928834/what-addressing-mode-is-used-in-mov-cx-bp6

Comment: what if i change mov si,2000h
mov bx,3000h
mov cx,[si]
mov [bx],cx will this be correct? and will it transfer the data i have in 2000h to 3000h ?